# Integration by inline u-substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

When integrating by $u$-substitution, instead of declaring a $u$ variable explicitly, the substitution can also be done inline like this:

$$
\int \! \sin x \cos x \, \textrm{d}x
= \int \! \sin x \cos x \, \frac{\textrm{d}(\sin x)}{\cos x}
= \int \! \sin x \, \textrm{d}(\sin x)
= \frac{\sin^2 x}{2} + C
$$

Is there a name for this approach to $u$-substitution? Also, might there be a reason to use or not use this approach? For example, might it be more error prone for some reason?

Comment: Observe that you may directly write $$\int \! \sin x \cos x \, \textrm{d}x
= \int \! \sin x \, \textrm{d}(\sin x). $$

Comment: @OlivierOloa Even better and even less error prone than declaring a $u$ variable. I can't wait to read comments about reasons to use or not use this approach.

Comment: Note that your integral has an error: the integral of $\sin x\cos x$ is not $-\cos x$!

Comment: @RoryDaulton Oops, thanks for pointing that out. I fixed my question.

Comment: I'm not sure if this approach has a formal name. Perhaps "Anonymous Substitution"?

I usually add an extra step
$$\int\sin x\cos xdx = \int\sin x\cos xdx\cdot\frac{\frac{d(\sin x)}{dx}}{\frac{d(\sin x)}{dx}}=\int\sin x\cos x\frac{d(\sin x)}{\cos x}=\dots$$